# hadoop namenode not able to connect to datanode after restart

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a 4-node hadoop cluster. It is running fine.
I temporarily stop hadoop cluster using:

```
stop-dfs.sh
stop-yarn.sh
```

When I restart it using:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

all jps(hadoop processes) are running fine on all the 4 nodes,
but it is showing the following error log on running map-reduce job:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hduser4/QuasiMonteCarlo_14 21995096158_792628557/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).
There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

An option for the problem above is to reformat HDFS, but it will delete my existing data, which is not a proper solution for a production system.

Comment: take a look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/CouldOnlyBeReplicatedTo